# Why empty string is added in the output array while matching a string using regex pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn `regex` in javascript. While doing testing, my mind get confused on seeing the output.

Can you please explain why my output result array has empty string while using `*` in pattern and not in `+`.

PS: The inputs taken are just a sample simple string to learn.

Here's my sample code:

```
a='bb bbbb bbb'
a.match(/(bb)*/g) // O/P is  ["bb","","bbbb","","bb","",""]
a.match(/(bb)+/g) // O/P is ["bb","bbbb","bb"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*`, or [Kleene Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), in regular expressions means "zero or more", so it matches *empty string*.

The `+` means "one or more" instead, so it does not match *empty string*.

---

Given that we have as follows

```
a = 'bb bbbb bbb';
```

Let's represent it like this:

```
a = /^bb bbbb bbb$/;
```

where `^` is start of string and `$` is end of string.

Our pattern is `(bb)*`. This means that the engine will look for a sequence of two `b` "zero or more times". This means the pattern matches `bb` if the sequence is found or *empty string* otherwise.

Now step by step I'll use a dot (`.`) to represent regexp analysis.

**STEPS**

```
        STRING              MATCH ARRAY
start - /^.bb bbbb bbb$/ -> [ ]
    1 - /^bb. bbbb bbb$/ -> [ "bb" ]
    2 - /^bb .bbbb bbb$/ -> [ "bb", "" ]
    3 - /^bb bbbb. bbb$/ -> [ "bb", "", "bbbb" ]
    4 - /^bb bbbb .bbb$/ -> [ "bb", "", "bbbb", "", ]
    5 - /^bb bbbb bb.b$/ -> [ "bb", "", "bbbb", "", "bb" ]
    6 - /^bb bbbb bbb.$/ -> [ "bb", "", "bbbb", "", "bb", "", ]
    7 - /^bb bbbb bbb$./ -> [ "bb", "", "bbbb", "", "bb", "", "" ]
```

In `STEP 1` we have pushed `bb` since the pattern matched one sequence.

In `STEP 2` we have pushed `""` because the pattern matched *empty string*.

In `STEP 3` we have pushed `bbbb` because the pattern matched two sequences.

`STEP 4` -> `STEP 2`

`STEP 5` -> `STEP 1`

In `STEP 6` we have pushed `""` because the pattern matched *empty string* since, only one `b` was found.

Finally you encounter `$` token and it matches *empty string* again.

Note that if the string was `"bb bbbb bbbb"` the array would have been `["bb", "", "bbbb", "", "bbbb", ""]`

Comment: in grammar context, empty string is an empty set.

Comment: @dave ok.but then the output should be as  ["bb","","bbbb","","bb"] since the input array has only two empty strings. ie empty string between bb,bbbb & bbbb, bbb. Correct me If im wrong..

Comment: @PSivachandran I wrote a step by step parse to explain the presence of `""`.

Answer (score 2):

`*` means "match the preceding group zero or more times". The engine tries to match at the position directly after the first `bb` in the string. It finds a space, which means that `(bb)` matched "zero times", resulting in an empty match.

`+` means "match the preceding group at least one time", so every match has to include the character sequence `bb` in your case.

---

Explanation why you have two empty matches at the end:

The last "word" is `bbb`. The engine matches `bb`, no problem here. Then there is one `b` left. It matchs `(bb)` "zero times". Then it tries to match at the last position of the string, which is  between the last character and the end of the string. It again match es `(bb)` "zero times".

If you want to know how regular expression engines work in detail, I recommend the book ["Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do).