# a second repetition to an inner repetition in re module in python

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
grades = 'AAABBBACBACCCCCAABCABACCCCAABCBBCA'
re.findall('(?:a{3})*', grades)
```

here i want to find all strings which are multiples of three 'a' characters, however the result is a list of `''`, i.e.

`['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`

This syntax is from the re documentation

> To apply a second repetition to an inner repetition, parentheses may be used. For example, the expression `(?:a{6})*` matches any multiple of six 'a' characters.

i don't know where is wrong, can you help me?

i expect it to be `['AAA']` while the result is obviously not.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why empty string is added in the output array while matching a string using regex pattern in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14674291), [Why does String.match( / \d*/ ) return an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30360439), [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655164) and quite a few more.

Answer (score 5):

Zero is a multiple of three. To exclude zero-length matches, use "one or more", `+`.

```
(?:A{3})+
```

Also note that regex is case-sensitive.