# sed - why '[.]' matches with the beginning and end of a line?

Tags: regex, sed

Why the the beginning and end of a line is matched by the `[.]*` and how to avoid it?

It seems the patten matches with the word boundary but not sure if it is as designed and which specification it implements.

```
$ echo " a " | sed -n 's/[.]*/X/pg'
X XaX X

$ echo " a " | sed -n 's/[\b]*/X/pg'
X XaX X
```

Comment: `*` means "0 or more". It always match.

Comment: Possible duplicates: *[Why empty string is added in the output array while matching a string using regex pattern in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14674291)* and *[Why does `String.match( /\d*/ )` return an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30360439)*.

Comment: Content and title do not match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\b` inside brackets has no special meaning. It is just a list of characters.

`[.]*` and `[\b]*` match **zero** or more of the character(s) in brackets.

So they match any runs of one or more of the characters, where the empty strings immediately preceding and following a run of the character(s) are just part of that run.

They also match any empty string that is not immediately preceded or followed by a run of the character(s).

---

Replacing space with something more visible, your input is: `sas`

None of the characters `.`, `\` nor `b` appear in the string. So there are no runs of length one or longer. With this input, both `[.]*` and `[\b]*` are equivalent to "match empty string".

- the empty string between start of line and  first `s` matches
- the empty string between first `s` and `a` matches
- the empty string between `a` and second `s` matches
- the empty string between second `s` and end of line matches

These 4 matches explain the `X`s added to your sample output.

---

Using `\b` to mean word boundary is not standard, although some versions of `sed` accept it (or the related `\<` and `\>`).

It is safer not to use this extension, and certainly not with `*`.

Even versions of `sed` that appear to support it produce non-intuitive and inconsistent results.

For example, with GNU sed 4.8:

```
$ echo ,aa, | sed 's/\b/x/g'
,xaax,
$ echo ,aa, | sed 's/\b*/x/g'
,aa,
$ echo ,aa, | sed 's/\b\{1,\}/x/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: Invalid preceding regular expression
$ echo ,aa, | sed 's/\(\b\)\{1,\}/x/g'
,xaax,
```

With busybox sed 1.30.1:

```
$ echo ,aa, | busybox sed 's/\b/x/g'
,xaxa,
$ echo ,aa, | busybox sed 's/\b*/x/g'
,aa,
$ echo ,aa, | busybox sed 's/\b\{1,\}/x/g'
sed: bad regex '\b\{1,\}': Invalid preceding regular expression
$ echo ,aa, | busybox sed 's/\(\b\)\{1,\}/x/g'
,xaxa,
```

Even other programs like Perl require care:

```
$ echo ,aa, | perl -ple 's/\b/x/g'
,xaax,
$ echo ,aa, | perl -ple 's/\b*/x/g'
x,xaxax,x
$ echo ,aa, | perl -ple 's/\b{1,}/x/g'
'1,' is an unknown bound type in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\b{1, <-- HERE }/ at -e line 1.
$ echo ,aa, | perl -ple 's/(\b){1,}/x/g'
,xaax,
$ echo ,aa, | perl -ple 's/\b+/x/g'
,xaax,
```

Comment: the busybox incorrect results appear to be due to a longstanding bug: https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=5090